# Rails - Many to Many association (Adding User to Groups) SQLite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have a Many-to-Many relationship here.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :memberships
has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :memberships
has_many :projects, :through => :memberships
end
```

These are the three models that I have. I want to know how to add these users to projects. Must I create another array by grabbing the user_ids via POST and split them by ', ' so that a new array is formed? And this array can be used as a future reference for sending notifications to all the Users in the Project whenever the project is edited.

How do I get the Projects for a certain User when I run

```
user.projects
```

there has to be a way in which I should push the Projects to that certain User's Projects, right? Please help me out, guys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
project = Project.create(name: 'first project')
project2 = Project.create(name: 'second project')
user.projects << project << project2 

user.projects # [project, project2]
```